# Trying to understand equality of these two predicates

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have predicate $$P(k,n,m) = \{ k < n \} \cap \{ m^2 \leq k < (m+1)^2 \}$$

My question is, in my book, it is stated that

$$ P(k,n,m) = \{m^2 \leq k < n < (m+1)^2 \} \cup \{ m^2 \leq k < (m+1)^2 \leq n \} $$

How is this possible? How did we go from intersection to union?

Comment: Step by step ... The right-end defines an interval $[m^2, (m+1)^2)$ like eg. (with $m=2$) $[4,9)$. Thus, in order that the intersection is not empty, we must have that $n$ must not be to the left of $m^2$.

Comment: Thus, we have two possible (mutually exclusive) cases: either (i) $n$ is inside $[m^2, (m+1)^2)$, or (ii) $n$ is to the right of $(m+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\{k|k\lt n\}=\{k|k\lt n\lt (m+1)^2\}\cup \{k|k\lt(m+1)^2\le n\}$$

with the partition depending on whether $n\lt(m+1)^2$ or $(m+1)^2\le n$, so that:

$$P(k,n,m)=\{k|k\lt n\}\cap\{k|m^2\leq k\lt (m+1)^2\}$$

becomes:

$$P(k,n,m)=\left(\{k|k\lt n\lt (m+1)^2\}\cup \{k|k\lt(m+1)^2\le n\}\right)\cap\{k|m^2\le k\lt (m+1)^2\}$$

Apply the distribution law to get:

$$P(k,n,m)=\left(\{k|k\lt n\lt (m+1)^2\}\cap\{k|m^2\leq k\lt (m+1)^2\}\right)\\
\cup \left(\{k|k\lt(m+1)^2\le n\}\cap \{k|k|m^2\le k\lt (m+1)^2\}\right)$$

The intersections can then be simplified to give the result.

Answer (score 1):

$P(k,m,n)\iff (\; [P(k,m,n)\land n<(m+1)^2]\lor [P(k,m,n)\land (m+1)^2\leq n]\;).$